# How do you override layerClass in swift 3?

Tags: swift3

I'm trying to override the method `layerClass()` in swift 3 but I'm getting the error `Method does not override any method from its superclass`.
In swift 2.x I was doing like this, does anyone know the new syntax?

```
override func layerClass() -> AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Please check [the latest reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/2098374-layerclass) when you find `Method does not override any method from its superclass` with code which worked in former versions of Xcode/Swift.

> Declaration
>
> ```
> class var layerClass: AnyClass { get }
> ```

`layerClass` is now imported as a computed class property in Swift.

So, you need to override it like this:

```
override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}
```