# Is this overriding the method or not?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I recently was forced to update to Swift 3.0 and it seems like Xcode's conversion did not do a great job. Luckily, I am able to solve the majority of the issues manually, however, one has me a bit confused.

This line that overrode the `canBecomeFirstResponder` method in uiController worked prior to upgrading to Swift 3.0:

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

However, it now returns the error:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass.

However, removing the `override` bit doesn't seem to fix it, as it raises a different error that seems to contradict the previous one:

> Method 'canBecomeFirstResponder()' with Objective-C selector 'canBecomeFirstResponder' conflicts with getter for 'canBecomeFirstResponder' from superclass 'UIResponder' with the same Objective-C selector

Is there actually an override occurring? Why is Xcode giving me mixed messages here?

For reference, I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081027/how-do-you-override-layerclass-in-swift-3) and although it is very similar, it is about a class, and this is about a method. To be safe, I *did* try using the solution to that question and it further broke things and raised the same errors.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`canBecomeFirstResponder` was changed from a method in Swift 2.2 to a property in Swift 3.0. This means that you must change your code to override it as a property instead of a method.

```
 override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { return true }
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick tutorial to find out yourself:

- Mark / select / highlight `canBecomeFirstResponder`
- Press <kbd>⌘C</kbd>
- Press <kbd>⇧⌘0</kbd> (zero not O) to get the documentation window.
- Press <kbd>⌘V</kbd>
- Press <kbd>↩</kbd> (return)

Now you will see the declaration

```
var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { get }
```

Do you see the difference?

Comment: Apologies for asking a dumb question, but what do you mean by "mark" it?

Comment: I mean select /highlight it.